# Debug.Assert() isn't thrown

Tags: vb.net, ide, assert

I have the following code:

[image]

As you can see from the quickview tooltip, nNewCell.Style is Nothing.
Despite of that, the lines

```
Debug.Assert(nNewCell.Style IsNot Nothing)
Debug.Assert(nNewCell.Style.GUID <> "")
```

aren't thrown.

The IDE doesn't raise an exception or stop there, the IDE simply ignores these lines.

My project settings are Debug x86.

What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Project Properties ➤ Compile ➤ Advanced Compile Options**

You will see a checkbox for `Define DEBUG constant`. This must be checked for `Debug` functions to work. If it's not, they will be ignored and not compiled into your assembly.

[image]

This definitely seems like you are missing the `DEBUG` constant because your code should be throwing a NullReferenceException due to the line `Debug.Assert(nNewCell.Style.GUID <> "")` and your screenshot showing it was `Nothing`.

---

One quick note. This issue really simple to cause and I have lost a decent amount of time before tracking down issues related to this. When creating a new configuration, always copy the appropriate type (Debug or Release). Issues like this are usually caused by copying a Release or non-debug config, but then attempting to treat them as Debug.

Comment: Thank you. It seems my settings were lost on updating VS.